# How does one insert a MSSQL uniqueindex using PHP's PDO library and prepared queries?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Title pretty much says it all. Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE foobar (
    [guid] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL
);
```

and the following code snippet:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("
    INSERT INTO foobar (
        [guid]
    ) VALUES (
        :guid
    )
");
$stmt->bindValue(':guid', '0x5E73EFFFFBE83864DD8A23D32A9AB226', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

The reason it is a string and not just a pure integer is because of the way it is generated; like so:

```
/**
 * Generates a windows-style guid
 * Code here is adapted from http://guid.us/GUID/PHP
 */
function GUID() {
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid')) {
        return com_create_guid();
    } else{
        mt_srand((double)microtime()*10000); //optional for php 4.2.0 and up.
        $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
        $uuid = substr($charid, 0, 8)
               .substr($charid, 8, 4)
               .substr($charid,12, 4)
               .substr($charid,16, 4)
               .substr($charid,20,12);
        return "0x".$uuid;
    }
}
```

Profiling the SQL server shows that the query looks like the following:

```
INSERT INTO foobar (
    [guid]
) VALUES (
    '0x5E73EFFFFBE83864DD8A23D32A9AB226'
)
```

This query will not run correctly.

I'm struggling to figure out how to insert this value. I've tried to convert the value to decimal via base_convert(), but there is a precision loss when I do so. Surely there is a more straight forward way to insert this value no?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Have you tried running the sql statement directly against the database?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so of course writing out the problem delivers the solution. In a nutshell I should have never altered the method I got for generating the GUID. What should be done is the following:

```
function GUID() {
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid')) {
        return com_create_guid();
    } else{
        mt_srand((double)microtime()*10000); //optional for php 4.2.0 and up.
        $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
        $hyphen = chr(45);// "-"
        $uuid = chr(123)// "{"
            .substr($charid, 0, 8).$hyphen
            .substr($charid, 8, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,12, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,16, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,20,12)
            .chr(125);// "}"
        return $uuid;
    }
}
```

Then, alter the insert query as follows:

```
INSERT INTO foobar (
    [guid]
) VALUES (
    CAST('{5E73EFFF-FBE8-3864-DD8A-23D32A9AB226}' AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
)
```

I was under the wrong assumption that this would not cast properly.